# installing ruby on rails and error saying -bash: rvm: command not found

Tags: rvm

I was installing Ruby on rails, I had installed xcode, and use the following line to install rvm

\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

and then went to check the rvm

rvm | head -n 1

message I received was

-bash: rvm: command not found

using latest Mac High Sierra v10.13

Answer (score 0):

First check that rvm is installed or not using the following command:

```
rvm --version
```

If rvm is installed then it will give a corresponding installed version.

If rvm is not installed then follow the below mentioned link to install ruby using rvm on mac.

http://usabilityetc.com/articles/ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-rvm/